# PHP password_verify не работает

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, хеширование, password

Я решил попробовать освоить работу с MySQL через PHP по этому [видео-уроку](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvgOPJQA8Zk&list=PLvoBekrlHDgS4RKqlyqhaNna_84jvL6Z9&index=2&t=0s)

У меня возникла проблема при проверке пароля, хэшированного  помощью password_hash.

```
if (password_verify($data["password"],$user->password))
            {
            
            }
            else
            {
                $errors[]="Неверный пароль";
            }
```

И вне зависимости оттого, правильный или нет ввел я пароль, все равно выводит, что пароль неверный. Я нашел такие ответы на stackoverflow: [обрезается хэшированный пароль](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700628/password-verify-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82), [проблемы с кавычками](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1015766/password-verify-php). Ни одно из них не помогло - поле password стоит VARCHAR(191), а все кавычки в коде - двойные, кроме как в echo.

Вношу данные я так:

```
$user = R::dispense("users");
$user->login=$data["login"];
$user->email=$data["email"];
$user->password=password_hash($data["password"],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
R::store($user);
echo "<div style='color: green;'>Вы успешно зарегистрировались</div><br>";
```

Кое-что странно: попробовал `echo "$user->login"` и `echo "$user->password"` - выводит пустоту, хотя `$user->login` присутствует при проверки существования пользователя с таким логином и работает корректно, так что `$user->login` не должен быть пустым... Определяю `$user` через `$user=R::find("users","login=?",array($data["login"]));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, проблема в строчке с определением `$user` (`$user=R::find("users","login=?",array($data["login"]));`) Если заменить `find` на `findOne`, то все заработает!

Answer (score 1):

Вы используете стиль ООП, похвально. Но думаю проблема могла затеряться в нем. Мне проще писать в процедурном стиле. Также могу порекомендовать более мощный движок шифрования PASSWORD_BCRYPT (насколько я помню в доках написано что он помощнее дефолтного). Также предупреждаю после обновления php шифрования PASSWORD_DEFAULT то есть то которое по умолчанию может поменяться! В доках так и написано поэтому нужно четко указать алгоритм иначе после обновления php МОЖЕТ больше не работать сайт, ибо хешы и методы будут разные!
Попробуйте этот скрипт. **$password = "Ваш тестовый пароль";**

```php
<?php
$password = "passw2";
echo ("Введенный пароль ->".$password);
echo "<br>";
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
echo "Hash ->$hash";
echo "<br>";
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    echo 'Пароль правильный!';
} else {
    echo 'Пароль неправильный.';
}
?>
```

Comment: Тестовый скрипт сработал. В своем коде заменил в password_hash PASSWORD_DEFAULT на PASSWORD_BCRYPT. Я понял, что у меня $user->password не работает. Я его определяю так: $user=R::find("users","login=?",array($data["login"])); Что не так?